# @Pointcut around JpaRepository doesn't work with default methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-aop

I've a Spring Boot 2.3 project. I do large use of Spring Data REST, Spring JPA, Hibernate.

A typical repository in my application looks like this:

```
@Transactional
public interface ContactRepository extends JpaRepository<Contact, Long>, ContactCustomRepository<Contact, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Contact> {

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Query("FROM Contact c WHERE c.id=:id")
    Optional<ContactType> findByIdTest(@Param("id") long id);
}
```

This is my filter:

```
@Aspect
@Order(1)
@Component
@Log4j2
public class EntityCustomerFilterAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(public * javax.persistence.EntityManager+.*Query(..))")
    private void createQuery() {
    }

    @Around(value = "createQuery() && target(entityManager)")
    public Object applyFilter(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Object entityManager) throws Throwable {
        try {
            if (SecurityUtils.getLoggedRoles().contains(Role.ROLE_CUSTOMER)) {
                if (SecurityUtils.getLoggedId() != null) {
                    ((EntityManager) entityManager).unwrap(Session.class).enableFilter("customerFilter").setParameter("contactId", SecurityUtils.getLoggedId());
                    log.trace(">>>>Enabling filter customer {}", SecurityUtils.getLoggedUser().getSid());
                } else {
                    ((EntityManager) entityManager).unwrap(Session.class).enableFilter("customerFilter").setParameter("contactId", -1l);
                    log.warn("Logged ID is null. Customer filter cannot be applied");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("Unable to enable filter");
        }
        return pjp.proceed();
    }

}
```

When from a REST controller I invoke the method `findByIdTest` the filter defined by `EntityCustomerFilterAspect` is applied. On the opposite, if I invoke the default Spring JPA `findById` instead, the filter is not applied.
I don't see what's wrong and why the @Pointcut doesn't work with default methods.

Comment: `findById` doesn't use a query but rather uses the `find` method on the `EntityManager` even if you would be able to intercept this, the filters wouldn't apply in this case, those only apply to queries and not the `EntityManager.find` method.

Comment: @M.Deinum do you see a nice way to solve this? My goal is to add an automatic filter when a customer is logged in my application. I want he is able to see only his data. The filter I guessed was the best way to do that so I don't risk to forget to put the condition in the query.

Comment: The filter is an excellent solution **but** it simply won't work when you do a direct query through JPA based on the primary key. `EntityManager.find`. So unless you have HTTP method or otherwise that directly call this based on an id in the request, this shouldn't be a problem. If you want to work around this you would need to re-implement the `findById` using a query (which might lead to issues due to JPA mapping being ignored!). Nonetheless if someone directly uses `EntityManager.find` instead of the repository you still have the same issue of no filters.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks. Actually SDR expose that methods as REST resources. So I should customize the controller and call a custom findByIdCustom in order to avoid the problem. Thanks again for the clarification!